# Can't sync back to the PC from Mobile device

Tags: qfield, qfieldsync, qfield-cloud

I'm using 3.28.4 Firenze and QField on an Android device.  I have the free QField Cloud account.

I can make the project in QGIS, with an empty layer.  I've tried saving it both as qgz and qgs.

I can sync the project to the cloud.

I can input data in QField and it saves in there.

I've tried pushing the changes and synchronising the project.  QField tells me the files have been uploaded, and I can see them in the cloud.

What I CAN'T do is get the updated files back onto my pc. I've tried synchronising from the main plug in menu, and from the toolbar.  I've followed the few tutorials I could find, but nothing seems to work most of the time.  Every now and then, things will come across, but I haven't done anything different!

Cable sync seems to work fine 90% of the time.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?